# Symfony2 - Highcharts rendering a blank div

Tags: php, symfony, highcharts

I have just installed the Highcharts Bundle on Symfony 2.7, but I am already facing an issue while trying to reproduce the "Usage Example" from the documentation (cf https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md)

Here is my code :

### Controller

```
public function homepageAction() 
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
    $authorization = $securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_REGISTERED_USER');

    if ($authorization) {

        // Charts Test

        $ob = new Highchart();
        $ob->chart->renderTo('piechart');
        $ob->title->text('Browser market shares at a specific website in 2010');
        $ob->plotOptions->pie(array(
            'allowPointSelect' => true,
            'cursor' => 'pointer',
            'dataLabels' => array('enabled' => false),
            'showInLegend' => true
        ));
        $data = array(
            array('Firefox', 45.0),
            array('IE', 26.8),
            array('Chrome', 12.8),
            array('Safari', 8.5),
            array('Opera', 6.2),
            array('Others', 0.7),
        );
        $ob->series(array(array('type' => 'pie', 'name' => 'Browser share', 'data' => $data)));

        return $this->render('MVPBundle:User:homepage.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'chart' => $ob,
    ));

    } else {

        $url = $this->generateUrl('user_displayCompanyCreationForm');

        return $this->redirect($url);
    }
}
```

---

### View

```
<script src='{{ asset('bundles/mvp/js/jquery-2.1.4.js') }}' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='{{ asset('bundles/mvp/js/highcharts.js') }}' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='{{ asset('bundles/mvp/js/exporting.js') }}' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    {{ chart(chart) }}
</script>

<div id="piechart" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"> </div>
```

---

After some research, I understood that it could be linked with the import of the JS files, so I made sure the paths to the files were okay, and that Jquery was imported before Highcharts JS files, so I really don't see where the problem comes from... :(

I would appreciate any help ! :)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps :

I have just fixed the problem. It came from the jQuery dependency (not from the order of the imports, but the version of the imported file). Indeed, it didn't work with 2.1.4, whereas it does with 1.7.1 for instance... :)

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to wrong html ID

```
    $ob->chart->renderTo('piechart'); //This is looking for html element with id as piechart
    <div id="linechart" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"> </div>
```

Change it to

```
    $ob->chart->renderTo('linechart');
```

Comment: Indeed, this was a first mistake (I had tried to render other types of charts while debugging...). 
However, it still doesn't work :(